# Can Juniper SRX300 act as VPN Client/SOHO Router?

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn, juniper, junos, srx

I have a pair of Juniper SRX300 Services Gateway, that I was hoping to use at each end of a VPN Tunnel.  I can see how to setup the VPN server-end, but I am trying to find the documentation to configure the other unit as the "vpn client".  In other words, I want the remote end to act as a SOHO router (site-to-site?), putting all the devices behind it on the VPN, instead of having each PC/device have to run their own VPN client software.

Is this possible? What does Juniper/JUNOS call this mode?

Comment: It's called site-to-site VPN.  [SRX & J Series Site-to-Site VPN Configuration Generator](https://www.juniper.net/support/tools/vpnconfig/)

Comment: Thanks.  But that only tells me how to configure the server-side gateway.  How do I set up the remote site on an SRX?

Comment: it's site to site, there is no 'server-side'.  Server / client and site-to-site are different things.

Comment: @yoonix - I appreciate the help.  I guess I'm referring to the fact that the configuration generator generates the SRX config for the "local site", but not the "remote site".  I feel like I'm missing some key piece of the puzzle that brings this altogether. I found a page to configure an SRX and Cisco ASA, but oddly not two SRX devices. https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28120

Comment: Pretend you're at the remote site and fill in the info as if it's the local site.

Comment: Also, you might find a better target audience at [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).